# Array and linkedlist in java

Tags: java, arrays, api, linked-list

Can you explain this code to me, what does `arrays.aslist(job)` mean ?

```
String jobs[] ={"senior","programmeur","project manager"};
LinkedList<String> links = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(jobs));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as
>   bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination
>   with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and
>   implements RandomAccess.

Used to create quick list, like:

```
List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Answer (score 1):

The `arrays.aslist(job)` is converting your `String` array to a `List`. The Javadoc for `Arrays.asList` says

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

What it does is

- it creates a wrapper that implements `List<String>`, basically original array is now available as new list
- when you add it to a `new LinkedList<String>()` it copies all elements from the original array to new List. It creates a immutable copy of the original array

Answer (score 0):

Also, asList helps to get object based collections out of primitive arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` creates an [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) List from an array.

To get a mutable List from an immutable List , create a new List (in this case, LinkedList) passing the immutable List in to its constructor.